# internet explorer XMLhttp instead of internet controlls?

Tags: performance, vba, internet-explorer-8

I am using vba code to get information out of the web.
Everything is going fine, but it takes soooo long :(

I remember darkly that there is another way to get the information instead of creating an IE Object.

I think I dont need the IE Controlls. I am just loading one link after each other out of an sheet.

How is the other "way" working? Its something like XMLHttp?
Is there a difference for the code? shoudnt be, or?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
Function getPage(URLStr As String) As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim oHttpRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set oHttpRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    With oHttpRequest
        .Open "GET", URLStr, False
        .send
    End With
    Dim oHTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set oHTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    oHTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oHttpRequest.responseText
    Set getPage = oHTMLDoc
End Function
```

To call the function, use something like this:

```
Dim oHTMLDoc as MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set oHTMLDoc = getPage("http://www.example.com")
```

For this, you'll need to add references to both "Microsoft XML, v6.0" and "Microsoft HTML Object Library", then you can use the MSHTML library to parse through the code as you need.

Comment: +1  This is how I do it too.  However, if your doing a lot of links, don't create the http object inside the function - it's unnecessary overhead.  Create it, use it multiple times, then destroy it.